# what is the best way to store and save multidimensional dataset

Tags: python, pandas, image, multidimensional-array, opencv

Basically I have list of pre-processed image data(nested list) and corresponding target value in different list and zipped them

```
np.array(dataset_x).shape
>>> (253,32,32,3)

np.array(dataset_y).shape
>>> (253,1)

dataset = dataset_x + dataset_y
```

My target is shuffle them, split then train ,test and store model and dataset.I know split,store and load csv using `panda`, I wanted to used them , so i used `pd.DataFrame`

```
In : pdata = pd.DataFrame(dataset,  columns =['img' , 'target']) 
In : np.array(dataset).shape
In : data.shape
>>>(253, 2)
```

Now problem is ,
i was expecting this

```
In : pdata['img'].shape
>>>(253,32,32,3)
```

but instead i got

```
In : pdata['img'].shape
>>>(253,)
In : pdata['img'][0].shape
>>>(32, 32, 3)
```

I understand the problem but didn't know what is efficient way to solve, ended up converting them to list using `values.tolist()`. **What is the best way to store this type of dataset in `dataframe`?**

Second problem is , when i try to store `dataframe` using `to_csv()` and load them using `read_csv()`. the list of image turn into a string.

```
In : dataset= pd.read_csv(r"abc.csv") 
In : dataset['img'].shape
>>> (202,)

In : dataset['img'][0].shape
>>>AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'

In : dataset['img']
>>> 0      [[[0.03137255 0.03137255 0.03137255]\n  [0.015...
    1      [[[0. 0. 0.]\n  [0. 0. 0.]\n  [0. 0. 0.]\n  .....
    2      [[[0. 0. 0.]\n  [0. 0. 0.]\n  [0. 0. 0.]\n  .....
    3      [[[0. 0. 0.]\n  [0. 0. 0.]\n  [0. 0. 0.]\n  .....
```

**how to save the dataset and retrieve as the nested list ??**

Comment: The data is originally in a list, right? Do you need to use NumPy and/or Pandas?

Comment: _data looks like this (32, 32, 3) ``` array([[[3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], ..., [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]], ..., [[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], ..., [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]], dtype=uint8) ```_ That should go in your post. I was asking about `dataset_x` and `dataset_y`, is that what that is?

Comment: _and used numpy in preprocessing , before convert dataset into panda.dataframe._ I know that you did, I'm asking if you **must**. If you don't need numpy/numpy arrays for any other part of the program, then it would be a waste to import the entire library just for a small task. How are you doing the splitting, by the way?

Comment: This is difficult to follow, I think there's far too much going on in the post.

Comment: data looks like this (32, 32, 3)
`array([[[1,1,1] ..., [2, 2, 2]], ..., [[3, 3, 3], ....,[4, 4, 4]]], dtype=uint8)`
i need panda to shuffle and split, if i dont use this what could be the easiest  ?  and used numpy in preprocessing , before convert dataset into panda.dataframe.

Comment: Pardon? Did you delete and repost your comment?

Comment: i wasn't sure how to use code in comment, mistakenly used ```  .
`dataset_x ` is the image and `dataset_y` is target  binary value (yes /no ). i don't need numpy later if i solved first problem.  and for splitting i used `train_test_split()`

Comment: _I wasn’t sure how to use code in comment_ The answer is generally “don’t”, especially when it’s important to the question. It should get in the post itself.